# Oracle DB Create Table Only When Data Exists

Tags: oracle, create-table

When I try to create table using below statement
CREATE TABLE  <TABLE_NAME_1> AS
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME_2> WHERE <CONDITION_1> ;

I would like to understand is there any way, where oracle ignores creation of table when underlined select statement does not returns any rows.

i.e. if end users intent is to avoid unnecessary blank tables. Is there any way/feature provided by Oracle.

Comment: Sounds to me like there is a larger problem to be addressed.  Who's creating tables on the fly like this without knowing the conditions that would dictate whether they want/need to create the new table?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE <TABLE_NAME_1> 
AS 
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME_2> WHERE <CONDITION_1> ;
```

Will create the table with structure even if there is no data in the table.

`CTAS` once executed will create the table anyway.

If you want to create the table only when data is present in the selected table then you have to use the PL/SQL block as follows:

```
DECLARE
    CNT NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1)
      INTO CNT
      FROM <TABLE_NAME_2>;

    IF CNT > 0 THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE <TABLE_NAME_1> AS 
                           SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME_2> WHERE <CONDITION_1>';
    END IF;
END;
/
```